# Microservice is throwing 502 Bad gateway time out after some to perform load testing

Tags: java, microservices

I am using the microservice architecture and performing the load testing where main microservice is throwing the 502 Bad gateway timeout after some time e.g 1k user load, after completing the 400 user request then after it is start to throw the 502 Bad gateway timeout.

Service name
Eureka zuul Api gateway
Eureka server
Eureka client( main microservice)

Please  share your suggestions and let know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

This could be cause by your Rest/Grpc request pool getting filled and request being rejected. You can connect VisualVM to your application see whats happening on the Thread and Heap level